# SCRIPT14: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation, ckeditor gem error on IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor gem in my rails app and its not working on IE. It gives an error

```
SCRIPT14: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

ckeditor.js?body=1, line 63 character 140
```

I search it on google and saw some result (http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CKEditor-Not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operation and http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Not-enough-storage-error-IE7IE8) but I can not understand how can i implement it on my rails app using  gem "ckeditor_rails", "~> 4.0.2". please help!

Answer (score 0):

according to http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CKEditor-Not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operation

how to implement it?

1) please copy `vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` from ckeditor_rails gem to `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` of your project.

2) find

```
if(this.$.createStyleSheet)this.$.createStyleSheet
```

and replace with

```
if(false)this.$.createStyleSheet
```

3) cleanup cache of your browser and restart your server to see if it works.

honestly say, I don't try it for IE. But that's how rails assets pipeline works.

the new release v4.1 also has this piece of code. the bug may not be resolved by CKEDITOR team.

also see https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails/issues/17